# _perror returns non-NULL when given bad command

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, popen, windows-console

Visual C++ 2017 -- Console application

The only documentation I find for the Windows version of popen, namely _popen, says it is supposed to return a null_ptr when it fails. It says nothing about spewing a gratuitous error message to the console. Yet if returns non-null and spews.  I have not found a way to determine if the pipe connected. When I use fprintf to write to the bad pipe, it does not appear to fail either. Is this a bug in _popen, or am I doing it wrong? What is the workaround?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // This program is expected to write 
    // 00000000
    // Good
    // 
    // Instead it writes (e.g.), in this order,
    // 0082F2C0
    // Not good
    // '42' is not recognized as an interal or external command,
    // operable program or batch file.

    FILE* fp = _popen("42 is a no-good command", "w");
    std::cout << fp << std::endl;
    if (!fp) {
        std::cout << "Good" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not good" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: popen() is a Posix function, preserved in the MSVC++ CRT with a leading underscore because Windows once had a Posix sub-system.  It uses Unix sensibilities, the command you specify is passed to the command line processor, Cmd.exe.  Which will happily spew into your console if it is garbage, it does not redirect stderr.  That was considered a feature 25+ years ago, sending error messages through the pipe confuzzles the bejeezus out of what ever program uses the pipe.  Now it bejeezuses a Windows programmer :)  And no error, cmd.exe started just fine.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `_popen`() succeeds because it is executing whatever command you pass it within the context of a spawned copy of the command processor (the Command Prompt, usually `cmd.exe`).

(See **Remarks** section here: [_popen, _wpopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen)).

You can prove/recreate this by just opening a Command Prompt and typing your `"42 is a no-good command"`.

You should get the exact same error that is being produced by your program.